# Android TextView EditText New Line Spacing

Tags: android, textview

Anyone know how to get the new paragraph (\n or enter) spacing height for an edit text?

What I'm trying to do:
I would like to draw a line below all the text and make a big editing area like a notepad. At the moment, I'm able to get the line spacing through LineSpacingExtra, LineHeight, LineCount. However, none of this seems to allow me to get/set the new paragraph spacing. Any idea?

[image: Click to see screen shot]

Comment: TextView isn't really designed to display multiple paragraphs of text.

Comment: When i tested my code in pre-lollipop, it works perfectly and I found that it is working perfectly. And this issues is related to [a bug posted here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77941). By the way, I added LineSpacingMultiplier and ExtraLineSpacing for the edit text shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an issue and this issues is related to [a bug posted here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77941). By the way, I added LineSpacingMultiplier and ExtraLineSpacing for the edit text shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the Visual editor. Your code does work in the emu.

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

1. Using the `replace` method you need to filter escaped linefeeds (e.g. '\\n')
2. Only then each instance of line feed '\n' escape chars gets rendered into the actual linefeed

Comment: <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1\nText 2\nText 3"/>